# CGRect Collision With multiple CGRects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cgrect

I am new in to iPhone programming, I am currently working on ballsplit game. In this game, when my bullet hits any ball ball, I want it to create two new balls. My bullet and ball are both uiimageview.

Here is my code:

```
if ((CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.frame,Ball.frame)) && !(ball)){
    ball=TRUE;
    x=Ball.frame.origin.x;
    y=Ball.frame.origin.y;
    [self performSelector:@selector(createball)];
}
```

Here is my create ball function..

```
-(void)createball{
    if (ball) {
        imageMove1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50 ,50)];  
        UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball1.png"];
        [imageMove1 setImage:imag];
        [self.view addSubview:imageMove1];
        [ballArray addObject:imageMove1];

        imageMove2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50 ,50)]; 
        UIImage *imag1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball1.png"];
        [imageMove2 setImage:imag1];
        [self.view addSubview:imageMove2];
        [ballArray addObject:imageMove2];
        ball=FALSE;
        [self performSelector:@selector(moveball)];
    }
}
```

Now after creating these two uiimgeview, when bullet hits one of these two uiimageview I want  it to create another two uiimageviews. But problem that I face how we can get the frames of these new uiimageview...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you are new here, please remember to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also remember that proper grammar and code formatting are required here, and that this is not a coders-for-hire website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you move the bullet iterate trough array where you stored references to ball images:

```
for (UIImageView *ball in ballArray){
     //check for collision
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.frame,ball.frame)){
        //hit
    }
}
```

Check collision between balls:

```
for (UIImageView *ballOne in ballArray){
    for (UIImageView *ballTwo in ballArray){
        //check for collision
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ballOne.frame,ballTwo.frame) && ballOne != ballTwo){
            //hit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Alex for Quick response.but if my NSMutablearray have 4 balls at the same time then how to get the frame of balls which one hit by bullet..

Comment: I've added example how to check for collisions between balls.

Comment: thanx for helping me.i  try this..but  its not work for me..bcz when my bullet hit the imagemove1.then how its possible to call createball function again.and also create new uiimageview with the same name.same imageview2 is still on the screen..

Comment: Just call createBall where I've put //hit comment. And set the x,y coordinates to appropriate values.

Comment: Thanx dear @Alex but its not solve my problem.i already try it.